# sklearn KMedoids returns empty clusters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am using KMedoids from sklearn_extra.cluster. I use it with a precalculated distance matrix (metric='precomputed') and it used to work. However, we found a bug in the way the distance matrix was calculated and therefore had to implement it ourselves. Since then the KMedoids algorithm doesn't work anymore. This is the stacktrace:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 1 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[1]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (1).
  warnings.warn(enter code here
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 2 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[2]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (2).
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 3 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[3]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (3).
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 4 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[4]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (4).
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 5 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[5]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (5).
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 6 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[6]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (6).
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sklearn_extra\cluster\_k_medoids.py:231: UserWarning: Cluster 7 is empty! self.labels_[self.medoid_indices_[7]] may not be labeled with its corresponding cluster (7).
  warnings.warn(
```

I have checked the distance matrix, it is a two-dimensional nparray with dimensions of n_data x n_data where the values on the diagonal are zero, so that should not be the problem. All the values are between 0 and 1. We used to use [this algorithm for the Gower distance](https://pypi.org/project/gower/), but that did not work when we only had categorical data for some reason. All our values are boolean values. The Gower distance returned the following:

```
File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\gower\gower_dist.py", line 62, in gower_matrix
    Z_num = np.divide(Z_num ,num_max,out=np.zeros_like(Z_num), where=num_max!=0)
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' output (typecode 'd') could not be coerced to provided output parameter (typecode '?') according to the casting rule ''same_kind''
```

I also tried pyclustering KMedoids and that did work. However, you need to define the initial medoids yourself using pyclustering and the method I found for that did not work with categorical data. (see below)

```
initial_medoids = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(data, n_clus, kmeans_plusplus_initializer.FARTHEST_CENTER_CANDIDATE).initialize(return_index=True)
```

Stacktrace:

```
File "path_to_file", line 19, in <module>
    initial_medoids = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(data, n_clus, kmeans_plusplus_initializer.FARTHEST_CENTER_CANDIDATE).initialize(return_index=True)
  File "path\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyclustering\cluster\center_initializer.py", line 357, in initialize
    index_point = self.__get_next_center(centers)
  File "path\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyclustering\cluster\center_initializer.py", line 256, in __get_next_center
    distances = self.__calculate_shortest_distances(self.__data, centers)
  File "path\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyclustering\cluster\center_initializer.py", line 236, in __calculate_shortest_distances      
    dataset_differences[index_center] = numpy.sum(numpy.square(data - center), axis=1).T
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

My problem can be fixed in three ways, so I hope that someone can help me:

1. Someone knows why KMedoids by sk-learn doesn't work and can help me with that, so I can use it.
2. Someone knows what I'm doing wrong with the Gower function from PyPI, so I can use either pyclustering or sklearn.
3. Someone knows how I can easily find the initial medoids to use for pyclustering, so I can use pyclustering.

I have posted a simple version of the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import gower_distance as dist
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids

data = pd.read_csv(path_to_data)
dist = calcDist(data) # Returns NxN array where N is the amount of data points
# I'm using 8 clusters, which is the default, so I haven't defined it
kmedoids = KMedoids(metric='precomputed').fit(dist)
labels = kmedoids.predict(dist)
```

Answer (score 3):

I also received that warning (however using the euclidean-distance). using another initialization of the cluster cores fixed it for me:

```
kmedoids = KMedoids(metric='precomputed', init='k-medoids++').fit(dist)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - if it fixed it for you, it doesn't necessarily fix it for someone else using a different dataset.

Answer (score -2):

To get cluster labels from the trained model (i.e. train label),

```
data = pd.read_csv(path_to_data)
dist = calcDist(data)
kmedoids = KMedoids(metric='precomputed').fit(dist)
labels = kmedoids.labels_
```

To use `kmedoids.predict` with any predict data using the trained k-medoids model, you need to compute `N x K` distance matrix from `N` predict data to `K` medoids, **properly indexed**.

```
medoids = predictData[kmedoids.medoid_indices_, :]
distToMedoids = calcDistToMedoids(predictData, medoids) # with the same metric used in training
predict_labels = kmedoids.predict(distToMedoids)
predict_labels = np.argmin(distToMedoids, axis=1) # what .predict() does
```

You can check more from [the source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/scikit-learn-extra/blob/master/sklearn_extra/cluster/_k_medoids.py#L280-L306).

Comment: This is the not what the question is asking - the question is asking how to solve the bug with k-medoids returning empty clusters.